# Can not save Extension Builder 7.6.0 in TYPO3 7.6.9

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, extension-builder3

I can not save Extension Builder 7.6.0 in TYPO3 7.6.9. When I'm click save button it's alert messages:

Error while saving: Server responded with Status-Code: 0 
Status text: communication failure

[image: Error Screen Shoot]

Please help me. 
thanks.

Comment: there are many problem when you used TYPO3 with wamp, namespaec, path etc. I suggest to you go with Linux family.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I only had those problems if typo3 was installed in a subdirectory. So either move it to the Web root or adopt your vhost config